# How to change background color of gvisTable in Shiny App (R)

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I cannot get the background of the gvisTable in Shiny to be anything other than white.  I am trying this, but it does not work:

```
gvisTable(finalTable, options = list(page='enable', 
                                     width='1400px', height='300px',
                                     backgroundColor="black"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `cssClassNames` options:

```
require(shiny)
require(googleVis)
runApp(
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("googleVis on Shiny"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("table")
      ,tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", ".myTableHeadrow {background-color:red;} .myTablerow {background-color:yellow;}"))
    )
  ),
  server =function(input, output)({
    output$table <- renderGvis({
      ## Table with enabled paging
      tbl2 <- gvisTable(Population, options=list(page='enable', height=300, cssClassNames = "{headerRow: 'myTableHeadrow', tableRow: 'myTablerow'}", alternatingRowStyle = FALSE), chartid = "mytable")
      tbl2
    })    
  })
  )
)
```

[image: googleVis Example]